# Loop through a column in SQL using C# ( and compare its values with a variable )

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a large table which has an ID column and contains request/ticket info.

On a win form , I want to let user enter his request ID and get all the request info in a new form.

The place where I am facing a problem is how to loop through the values of only one column.

Here is what I have seen elsewhere and have tried to implement[my datatable name is st]:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("dbo.table_submission");
DataRow[] foundRows = dt.Select("ID =" + i);
        if (foundRows != null )
        {
            Status status = new Status();
            status.Show();
        }
```

Comment: The DataTable has a method called Select that could retrieve matching rows for you without you using an explicit loop

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about a stored procedure.But I need to loop through each value one by one and compare it to a variable.

Comment: No there is a SELECT method of the DataTable object. And you do NOT need to loop row by row for this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataTable has a [Select method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) that could retrieve matching rows for you without you using an explicit loop.

For example, assuming that the value you are searching for is in a column named `RequestID`

```
int yourValueToSearch = 1;

DataRows[] foundRows = dt.Select("RequestID = " + yourValueToSearch);
if(foundRows != null && foundRows.Length > 0)
{
    DataTable result = foundRows.CopyToDataTable();
    // Pass the result table to your form....

}
```

This could also be a string but you need to add proper quoting

```
string yourValueToSearch = "ABC123";
DataRows[] foundRows = dt.Select("RequestID = '" + yourValueToSearch + "'");
```

Eventually you could also use Linq

```
var foundRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(x => x.Field<int>("RequestID") == yourValueToSearch)
                  .ToArray()
```

Comment: I am getting a weird error that my column [ID] was not found (which is the name of column in discussion) . Is this syntax compatible with sql server or mysql? Also , what is this `foundRows.Length > 0` for?

Comment: The evaluation of this syntax is done by the NET Framework, not by any database engine (Remember a datatable is a disconnected object). The check on the array foundRows is required if you want to use CopyToDataTable otherwise you will get an exception. About the ID column I can't say. The name should match the column name of the datatable

Comment: The documentation about the syntax used by the filterexpression in the Select method can be found in the [DataColumn.Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) docs page

Comment: Sorry to have bothered you , I see you have given me the link to the documentation , I will go and help myself. Thank you.

Comment: No nothing wrong here, but we are talking about columns names. That line just declares the table without any column. How do you fill the datatable. Columns are created before filling the table and usually they takes the names of the column on the database table.